# How would you set up the folllowing differential equation in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have 20 coupled differential equations and would like to solve them numerically in Mathematica. How would I set this up in some vectorised way?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach defines a vector, `state`, that is differentiated to get the left hand side of the system equations.  The `state` vector is also the variable to be solved for and plotted.  The right hand side of the DE is the vector `rhs`.  The initial values of `state` are a third vector, `icvalues`.  The ICs are expressed vectorially as `ics`.  A vectorized solution is

```
neq = 3;
tmax = 3 π;

state = Table[θ[k][t], {k, 1, neq}];

rhs = Table[Sum[Sin[θ[k][t] - θ[j][t]], {j, 1, neq}] +
    Cos[θ[k][t]] - t Sin[θ[k][t]], {k, 1, neq}];

odes = D[state, t] == rhs;

icvalues = Table[k/neq, {k, 1, neq}];
ics = state == icvalues /. t -> 0;

soln = NDSolve[{odes, ics}, state, {t, 0, tmax}];

Plot[Evaluate[state /. soln], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

### Edit:  An example using a stochastic DE

Here is a code sample that may be useful in building your model and it may represent something close to the stochastic DE mentioned in your comment.  A brief explanation and comparison to the above ODE follows the plot.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

neq = 3;
tmax = 3 π;

state = Table[ToExpression["θ" <> ToString[k] <> "[t]"],
     {k, 1, neq}];

rhs = Table[Sum[Sin[state[[k]] - state[[j]]], {j, 1, neq}] +
    Cos[state[[k]]] - t Sin[state[[k]]], {k, 1, neq}];

aug = rhs \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[t];

sde = Thread[Thread[\[DifferentialD]state] == aug];

icvalues = 
  Table[k/neq, {k, 1, neq}]  (* your float values go here *);
ics = {Head /@ state, icvalues};

proc = ItoProcess[sde, state, ics, t, 
         w \[Distributed]WienerProcess[0, .05]];

SeedRandom[123]
td = RandomFunction[proc, {0, tmax, tmax/100}]["Path"];
pts = Table[{pt[[1]], pt[[2, k]]}, 
        {pt, td}, {k, neq}] // Transpose;

ListLinePlot[pts, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Things are a little different for a stochastic DE.  First, the `state` variables are renamed from `θ[1][t]` to `θ1[t]`, etc.  `rhs` is largely the same, except the variable names are taken from the `state` vector, instead of being hardwired into `rhs`.  The RHS is then augmented to change its form and to add the same amount of noise to each derivative, which gives `aug` as a vector.  The stochastic DE `sde` is then formed using `Thread`.  In the plain ODE case `Thread` was not required, but here it is.  The `icvalues` are the same, but the form of the ICs themselves has changed.  All of this is pulled together by `ItoProcess`.  Note that 2nd argument of `ItoProcess` is the Output.  Here we are asking `ItoProcess` to output all of the functions given in the vector `state`.  We could output only the first function with `state[[1]]`, or several functions with `state[[{8,10,12}]]`.  And there are other options for the Output, in the docs.  Note that the parameter list used above with `ItoProcess` can also be used with the `StratonovichProcess` function.

`RandomFunction` generates the solution.  You can add another parameter to `RandomFunction` to generate more solutions and you can remove `SeedRandom` to generate different solutions.  `RandomFunction` returns a `TemporalData` object, which takes the "Path" argument and lots of other arguments, so see the docs.  If you add a parameter to `RandomFunction`, you may have to use `["Path",n]` to get the data points for the nth solution.

The path data is in the form {t, {$\theta$1, $\theta$2, ...}}.  It must be re-cast as {{{t,$\theta$1}, ...},{t,$\theta$2},...} ...} for plotting.  `pts` is a list of time histories that can be readily plotted.

If you need a different noise function for each state variable, see the example [`SimulationOfProcessesDrivenByVectorNoiseProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/SimulationOfProcessesDrivenByVectorNoiseProcess.html) in the docs.

Comment: This is lovely. I have one more question. Suppose I would like to add a Gaussian noise with a given variance, N(0, 0.05), to the rightside of the above equation. This would be stochastic differential equation. How would I implement this in Mathematica? The following problem looks very similar, but I expect it to give the same result as that of ordinary differential equation in the limit of zero standard deviation of the noise, which I am unable to recover if I follow what is done here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1300502

Comment: @titanium  Added stochastic example based on method shown in the cited reference.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows, making use of `Table`.

```
SeedRandom[1234]; sol =  NDSolve[Union[
Table[\[Theta][i]'[t] ==  Sum[Sin[\[Theta][i][t] - \[Theta][j][t]], {j, 1, 20}] + 
Cos[\[Theta][i][t]] - t*Sin[\[Theta][i][t]], {i, 1, 20}], 
Table[\[Theta][i][0] == RandomReal[], {i, 1, 20}]], 
Table[\[Theta][i][t], {i, 1, 20}], {t, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[\[Theta][12][t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]